# C# Winforms: Custom control doesn't redraw on size change by Docking

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I have a custom control derived from 'Label' where I draw a gradient background. It works, but when I dock the control in the form, it seems that because of that, my gradient isn't drawn properly (The gradient is repeated several times if you know what I mean). I hooked on several events (OnResize, OnSizeChanged,...) where I Invalidate() the control, but it still doesn't redraws itself properly with the correct size.

The code of my custom control:

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            //base.OnPaintBackground(e);
            // Fill with gradient 
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(_gradientBrush, ClientRectangle);
        }
```

Comment: How do you create the gradient brush? It has a size and if your control is larger than that it will be repeated.

Comment: Crystal ball says that you forget to recreate the brush when the control is resized.  Just don't store _gradientBrush, there is no point to that.  Brushes are very, very cheap to created, very expensive to keep around.  Create it when it you need it and you don't have this problem.

Comment: Ah, you're right! I feel so silly, thanks!